# cannot extract elements on linkedin page using xpath variable

Tags: c#, xpath, linkedin-api

Following is my C# code

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using HtmlAgilityPack;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml("https://www.linkedin.com/in/urbanwell");     
        var results = new List<string>();
        var LinkedInCompany="(//div[contains(@class, 'profile-card-extra')]//div[contains(@id, 'website-view')]//a)[1]";
        HtmlNodeCollection siteFields = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(LinkedInCompany);
        Console.WriteLine("siteFields COUNT = {0}", siteFields.Count);
      }
}
```

Here siteFields is `null`, whereas if i use `Chrome` extension of `xpath` `(//div[contains(@class, 'profile-card-extra')]//div[contains(@id, 'website-view')]//a)[1]`, i get results as website on the page.-- > http://urban-well.com/

Please suggest, had linkedin changed format of the page or something else which chrome can automatically detect but not my code

Answer (score 0):

It seems that LinkedIn requires to be logged in to its website to display this information. I have compared the two HTML (Anonymous user and logged in user), and the information you are looking for, is only available for logged in user.

To fix this, you have to log into Linkedin before loading the web page. You should be able to do it by sending a POST request similar to the one generated by LinkedIn login form. Use the browser debugger (network tab) to find the request to reproduce in your C# application.

Moreover, LinkedIn generates some of its content with client side JavaScript, so you will not be able to scrap such content using C#.